# how to pass a session value in different route in express session?

Tags: node.js, express, session, socket.io

I have creating a username session of success login in controller and i wan the session value in the route back so that pass it with socket.io emit but the problem is it is coming undefined in the route

```
    app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.errors= null;
  res.locals.user= null;
  res.locals.username = req.session.username;
  res.locals.pageViews = req.session.views;
  next()
```

}

i Am the express session

whenever i doing

```
 console.log(username);
```

in the route it is coming undefined

I tried with

```
app.global
```

also but not working
Any help is Welcome
Thank You

Comment: Where are you placing the console.log? Also, seems like you would want to try console.log(res.locals.username) instead

Comment: its after the middleware and yes i want the session var in route so that i can store it in a var

Comment: if its after this middleware, then i think console.log(res.locals.username) will do the trick to at least log. and if you're setting const username = res.locals.username, then your original console.log(username) should also work

Comment: its not working . I tried with the const as well but is its coming undefined

Comment: I would suggest posting the entire set of example code, because it's hard to troubleshoot without being able to see or reproduce the issue you're describing.